# Specific SQL queries with JOIN vs. multiple methods

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a NodeJS app and a mysql database. I use the [mysql npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) to access it.

Very often in my SQL schema I have relation between tables like this :

```
Table User :
SERIAL id
...

Table Group
SERIAL id
...

Table Group_Constraints
SERIAL ConstraintId
...

Table UserToGroup
BIGINT UserId
BIGINT GroupId

Table GroupToConstraint
BIGINT GroupId
BIGINT ConstraintId
```

Now, In my User model, I want to have a function that gives me the users, their groups and the user's group properties.

For now, I do a big custom SQL request with some JOINS. It works, but it leads me with many "custom" functions like *getUsersWithGroupAndConstraints*.
As I have this design in many different place of my code, it leads to something very hard to maintain.

I wish my code where a bit more generic and have a User/Group/Constraint model,that I would then Query this way :

```
User.getAll().forEach(user => 
   Group.getAll(user).forEach(group =>
       Constraint.getAll(group)))
```

But it would lead from 1 SQL query to User.length*Group.length SQL Queries.

I cannot find a way to achieve a *clean* design, without having a HUGE amount of SQL queries and therefore, I guess, very poor performances.

How can I do this ?

Comment: To me it seems that you would like to have an ORM functionality that results in the same SQL query that you would be issuing in getUsersWithGroupAndConstraints(). Is this really more effective than creating a fix SQL query?

Comment: @Shadow I took a look at Sequelizejs but setting it up in my application will be a lot of work as the application is already pretty big. I'm wondering if there is a 3rd choice